# Facebook sharer // What is this thing called that is shown beside the timestamp

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-sharer

Can anyone tell me what is this called in opengraph

I'm trying to figure it out and change it but i cant find this on the opengraph documentation

[image]

Comment: That’s called the App Attribution, that simply shows which app was used to make this post. And it is not directly related to Open Graph.

Comment: Got it, thanks! can you post this as a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s called the **App Attribution**, that simply shows which app was used to make this post.

And it is not directly related to Open Graph.